# Draw a convex hull using the given points in java/android

Tags: java, android, polygon, convex-hull

I have some 2D points given and i want to draw a polygon using those points. This polygon must pass through all the given points means there is no such point which is inside or outside the polygon.

For example: if i have points like: (0,0), (1,1), (-1,-1),(-1,1) and (1,-1) and if i want to draw a polygon using those then my points array should be sorted in following manner:

(1,1) -> (1,-1) -> (-1,-1) -> (-1,1) -> (0,0) -> (1,1) OR

(1,1) -> (0,0) -> (-1,1) -> (-1,-1) -> (1,-1) -> (1,1)

but it cant be:

(1,1) -> (0,0) -> (-1,-1) -> (-1,1) -> (-1,1) -> (1,-1) -> (1,1)

For drawing the polygon, i am using [drawLine](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawLine%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) function and drawing lines from one to another point and finally from last to first point.

Is there any algorithm or code available for this?

thanks!!

Comment: But can it be (1,1) -> (0,0) -> (1,-1) -> (-1,-1) -> (-1,1) -> (1,1) for example ? Can it pass multiple times by (0,0) ? What are you trying to do exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

A quick search in google : [convex hull algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms), and here is a [Java implementation](http://www.dr-mikes-maths.com/DP-convex-hull-java-code.html).

EDIT : re-read your question and realised it is not what you wanted. The title "Convex Hull" can be misleading...

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not as trivial as it seems. IMHO its a special form of the [travelling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), but without intersecting paths.